# Wget starts fine but gets locked out on chromebook. Why?

Tags: debian, http, wget, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Did I try to connect to something I shouldn't have, locking wget out until reboot?

On a chromebook, enable Debian, and use apt to install wget. Then if we do

```
$ wget http://www.example.com/ -O /tmp/x
--2023-07-28 10:29:56--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 93.184.216.34, 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|93.184.216.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1256 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: '/tmp/x'

/tmp/x 100% 1.23K --.-KB/s in 0s

2023-07-28 10:29:56 (26.4 MB/s) - '/tmp/x' saved [1256/1256]

$ wget http://www.example.com/ -O /tmp/y
--2023-07-28 10:30:02--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 93.184.216.34, 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|93.184.216.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1256 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: '/tmp/y'

/tmp/y 100% 1.23K --.-KB/s in 0s

2023-07-28 10:30:02 (19.2 MB/s) - '/tmp/y' saved [1256/1256]

$ wget http://www.google.com/ -O /tmp/z
--2023-07-28 10:30:29--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4009:801::2004, 142.250.190.100
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4009:801::2004|:80... ^C
$ wget http://www.example.com/ -O /tmp/w
--2023-07-28 10:30:43--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946, 93.184.216.34
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946|:80...
```

we see HTTP requests work fine, until I make the, perhaps, suspicious one to Google, upon which wget seemingly gets blacklisted in some unseen layer. Or maybe I'm just paranoid.

Wget starts getting stuck, and needs CTRL+C to stop.

The only way to get wget working again is to restart the chromebook.

curl? curl has no problem at all. But curl was installed automatically when we enabled Debian.
wget we added manually via apt. Outside of Debian the stock chrome chromebook browser also has no problems.

But both curl and wget are just their Debian versions. Yes, I haven't checked yet if the User-Agent is what gets blacklisted. Anyway, a secret middleman censor deep in the HTTP [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack)?!